# Kivy grouped checkboxes (radio buttons) all clicking together, and from anywhere on the screen?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Here is what I thought was a very simple screen config, and I get three radio buttons. But clicking anywhere on the screen results in the third radio button selecting - you cannot select first or second radio button, and why does it select when the user clicks anywhere on the screen instead of just on the radio button? Clicking anywhere a second time unselects the third item.

```
<FirstProfile>
    id: firstprofile

    disc_1: disc_1
    disc_2: disc_2
    disc_3: disc_3

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,1,1,1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size

    FloatLayout:

        CheckBox:
            id: disc_1
            pos_hint: {'x':0.05,'center_y':0.7}
            group: "disc"
            active: False

        Label:
            text: "Disc 1"
            pos_hint: {'x':0.25,'center_y':0.7}
            text_size: 200,80
            halign: 'left'
            valign: 'middle'

        CheckBox:
            id: disc_2
            pos_hint: {'x':0.05,'center_y':0.65}
            group: "disc"
            active: False

        Label:
            text: "Disc 2"
            pos_hint: {'x':0.25,'center_y':0.65}
            text_size: 200,80
            halign: 'left'
            valign: 'middle'

        CheckBox:
            id: disc_3
            pos_hint: {'x':0.05,'center_y':0.6}
            group: "disc"
            active: False

        Label:
            text: "Disc 3"
            pos_hint: {'x':0.25,'center_y':0.6}
            text_size: 200,80
            halign: 'left'
            valign: 'middle'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have not set any sizes for the `CheckBoxes`, so each `CheckBox` gets assigned the default `size_hint` of `(1,1)`, meaning each one is the same size as their parent `FloatLayout`. When you click anywhere on that `FloatLayout`, the last `CheckBox` added ("Disc 3") gets the event and claims it for itself, and the others never see the event.

Here is a modified version of your `kv` that sets some sizes:

```
<FirstProfile>
    id: firstprofile

    disc_1: disc_1
    disc_2: disc_2
    disc_3: disc_3

    FloatLayout:
        CheckBox:
            id: disc_1
            pos_hint: {'x':0.05,'center_y':0.7}
            group: "disc"
            active: False
            size_hint: None, None
            size: sp(32), sp(32)

        Label:
            text: "Disc 1"
            pos_hint: {'x':0.25,'center_y':0.7}
            text_size: 200,80
            halign: 'left'
            valign: 'middle'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.texture_size

        CheckBox:
            id: disc_2
            pos_hint: {'x':0.05,'center_y':0.65}
            group: "disc"
            active: False
            size_hint: None, None
            size: sp(32), sp(32)

        Label:
            text: "Disc 2"
            pos_hint: {'x':0.25,'center_y':0.65}
            text_size: 200,80
            halign: 'left'
            valign: 'middle'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.texture_size

        CheckBox:
            id: disc_3
            pos_hint: {'x':0.05,'center_y':0.6}
            group: "disc"
            active: False
            size_hint: None, None
            size: sp(32), sp(32)

        Label:
            text: "Disc 3"
            pos_hint: {'x':0.25,'center_y':0.6}
            text_size: 200,80
            halign: 'left'
            valign: 'middle'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.texture_size
```